# Are questions about how to approach an algorithm off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

Here is one I'm unsure about [Assistance on starting project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58091028/assistance-on-starting-project)? The question asks where to start to approach what will involve a *sweeping-lines* algorithm. He is obviously a beginner that truly needs help to be pointed in the right direction on how to approach the problem. He has gone to great length to accurately describe the problem and hasn't asked the typical ("Code it for me") question, but instead asked:

> I am unsure how to begin this program because I will not be using a 64x64 array, instead I will be working with a 1x1024 array holding all color information.

There are a number of *"terms of art"* that will point him in the right direction such as *"sweeping-lines"* and *"simulate 2D array from 1D array"*, that someone new is unlikely to stumble across without being pointed in the right direction.

I am unclear on whether we close the question ("scram, go ask your TA"), or whether this is a valid question that seeks help on how to approach a problem. (it's not a recommend a book, library, etc.... type).

So do we close it, or is this one a valid question?

Comment: Is there a single, objectively correct, answer to that question or is there a multitude of different ways to go about it?

Comment: It's a 2-part question, but yes there is 1 accepted way (the sweepline algorithm) and the naive solution (the difference being efficiency) and the second part there is only one solution simulate a 2D array from a 1D array. From my thinking that is the extent of the information needed before requiring the asking of a second question when he runs into a specific problem later?

Comment: The code is copied verbatim from [this web page](https://www.coursehero.com/tutors-problems/Computer-Science/9105304-Hello-the-problem-is-attached-so-i-finished-the-first-part-of-the-pr/).  Why he deleted some of it is hard to guess, probably because the pointer expressions blew his mind.  We can't reasonably guess at it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be closed as too broad. It's a typical "how do I do my whole project" question.

If had been narrowed down to just be about the algorithm, or just about how to implement an established algorithm, it could have been on-topic. As it stands, we don't know if their problem is with understanding the algorithm, or if they don't know how to write the code in C, or if they have written code but it isn't working.

Many pure algorithm questions, such as those of the nature of establishing the most efficient algorithm for a problem regardless of programming language, are better off at https://cs.stackexchange.com/.

However, there is no attempt of the OP to even start solving the problem. This may be because they simply don't know, or it may be because they want someone to do their homework. We don't care why, they need to make an attempt, or otherwise we can't narrow the question down to a specific technical problem.

It is a common pattern from some users to copy/paste their homework assignment, then dump some unrelated code with it, hoping that the presence of random code will save the question from getting closed. Not saying that this is the case here, but then again we don't care *why* someone asks a question, we just care about the question being narrow and answerable. Preferably it should not contain unrelated "fluff" either.

Peeking at https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

> **too broad** - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it is probably too broad for our format
>
> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

This is exactly the case here. We can't being to answer, because one user could post an answer about the algorithm and another about the C implementation, and yet another user post a whole book covering all of it. Which answer is correct?

I ended up directing the OP to the SO C chat, which is probably the best place to go for open-ended stuff like this. Alternatively, if they could narrow it down to an algorithm-only problem, it could be asked on the CS site.